# What is the best method of manipulate a MySQL database from a desktop application?

Tags: c#, php, .net, mysql, html

I'm developing an application that depends on sending and receiving data from a MySQL database. This is a .NET application written in C#. I already know that I could use ADO.NET to access the database directly, but I'm using a shared server so direct access to the database remotely is not allowed and a dedicated server account is just to expensive at this point in development. I was thinking about using the application to send a encrypted SQL request using php and then the server will return a encrypted XML file containing the data that was requested, but I don't know maybe that would be too slow, any suggestions?

Comment: Using ADO.NET is the best solution if you already know how to use ADO.NET.  You do know you can store your database localy.  You don't need to host the database yourself.  You could use a portable version of MSSQL for instance, an Access Database, there are lots of solutions.

Comment: $10!?... more like 60 bucks a month for software that wont be making dime off of for a good while. And I don't have a reliable enough infrastructure to host my own database right now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about SSH tunneling your requests / responses?  There are SSH libraries to enable this, then use ADO.NET through the SSH tunnel?

Comment: I did look into that, but I thought it might be difficult to put a portable solution inside the application and have It work correctly on every machine.